# problem protecting a directory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have created a .htaccess and .htpasswd files, and stored them in the folder I want to protect and when I navigated to that folder, I was asked for the username and passowrd (stored in the .htpasswd file) after entering the username and password, I got a 500 Internal server error. I have used the files on both localhost (windows) and on a web server (linux I guess) both gave the same result mentioned.

this is my .htaccess file:

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Please enter your ID and password"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user 
order deny,allow
```

Comment: Could give us the error-message from your Apache-Logs?

Comment: @pex: Where can I find the error log??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that your `.htpasswd` file is really located at the very root of the server's filesystem along with `/bin`, `/usr`, `/home`, and others (rather than inside the part of the filesystem served to web browsers).

According to Apache documentation ([1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile), [2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax)), `AuthUserFile` expects a file path (as if you were in ServerRoot, usually `/usr/apache` or similar, and trying to locate the file from the Unix shell). It cannot be a URL, either absolute or relative. Correct your `.htpasswd` file path accordingly.

Note that if possible, you shouldn't put the `.htpasswd` file inside a `public_html` or `htdocs` folder, because any configuration error could not only allow unauthorized access to the files you want to protect but also the authorized usernames and hashed passwords.

Comment: OK, I`m now testing on localhost (Windows 7), should the AuthUserFile be C:/wamp/www/.htpasswd?

Comment: it worked with me after setting the AuthUserFile to C:/wamp/www/.htpasswd ... but when I uploaded the file after changing the path, it didn`t work. Note: I`m using x10hosting free service.

Comment: @sikas: Your web host supports PHP, right? Try uploading a PHP file that only contains `<?php phpinfo();` and see what the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is. That should help you determine where your web site is on the server.

Comment: I have done this, and I got this /home/sikas/public_html/ location to the file ... what should I do with this?

Comment: @sikas: Use `AuthUserFile /home/sikas/public_html/.htpasswd` if your .htpasswd file is at `http://mysubdomain/.htpasswd`, `AuthUserFile /home/sikas/public_html/secret-files/.htpasswd` if it is located at `http://mysubdomain/secret-files/.htpasswd`

Comment: @idealmachine: I have be able to solve the problem, it seems that denying access to both .htaccess and .htpasswd from the .htaccess caused the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute hosting path, eg:

```
/home/content/14/5267714/html/.htpasswd
```